# $\forall\,x,\,y\in\mathbb{R} : [x + y] = [x] + [y]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Can you please help me proving the identity

---

$\forall\,x,\,y\in\mathbb{R} : [x + y] = [x] + [y]$, where $[\alpha]$ means the integer part of $\alpha$?

---

I figured out that it holds for $x,\,y\in\mathbb{Z}$, $x = 0$ (or $y = 0$) or $x = y = 0$.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: $x=y=1.9$ holds?

Comment: Should be $\displaystyle \left\lfloor x\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor y\right\rfloor \leq \left\lfloor x + y\right\rfloor.$  Provable via $\displaystyle x = \left\lfloor x\right\rfloor + r_x, ~y = \left\lfloor y\right\rfloor + r_y, ~~ 0 \leq r_x, r_y < 1.$

Comment: My comment was deleted, I guess because the moderator didn't like my calling out the bad behaviour here at MSE. Anyway, I feel it should be reiterated so that the OP realises that they didn't do anything wrong, even though their question was downvoted and closed without anyone giving any advice for how to improve it---not that it really needs any improvement. This kind of behaviour is toxic and endemic on MSE. My comment had upvotes, so clearly others agreed. I copy it below, verbatim.

Comment: New member joins // new member posts perfectly reasonable question, explaining what they've done and where they're stuck // politely asks for help // gets ridiculed, even a close vote(!?). Oh MSE, how you have fallen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is false as stated. Take $x =  1.5$, $y = 1.5$. Then, $[x] = 1$, $[y] = 1$, but $$[x+y] = 3\ne 2 = [x] + [y]$$